# Listar últimos 5 tweets com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, twitter-api

Preciso listar os últimos 5 *tweets* de um usuário do Twitter, e preciso que apareça somente o texto e a data. Estou tentando pelo *widget* do próprio Twitter, mas está muito complicado. Alguém teria uma outra solução para isto?

Comment: Mostre de que forma está complicado, até onde chegou e onde parou. Creio que ficará mais objetiva a pergunta assim.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma timeline incorporada, que é apenas um código javascript que gera a timeline no seu site. Veja mais: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines#user

A alternativa é usar a API do Twitter, só que não há como acessá-la diretamente do javascript, pois ela usa autenticação OAuth. Se houver a opção de fazer a partir do seu backend e acessar o resultado diretamente do seu servidor, assim você pode decidir como ele será apresentado. Para isso, veja: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline